# why is my texture split and not one image?

Tags: texturing

All i did was add new material to a plane mesh, then i applied a image texture. why does it look like this?

[image: image texture on plane mesh]

Comment: maybe you need to UV unwrap it?

Comment: if I'm not mistaken U then UV unwrap?

Comment: you got it man! why don't you post and answer so i can 1+ it!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Glady's comment i have discovered that my mesh what not UV unwrapped. This done by going into edit mode click U on the keyboard, followed by selecting "UV unwrap."